How to browse Microsoft Public Symbol Server
Is it possible to find all .pdb files for exact windows binary file from windows 7 to windows 11? For example i wan't to find all .pdb files for ntoskrnl.exe, including historic from Windows 7 if it is possible

Think that not. if you have concrete  binary ( say ntoskrnl.exe ) you can format url for request it pdb, but browsing for all versions.. doubt

@RbMm how can i format url to request at least specific? Maybe some checksum or something?

you need found IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY with Type IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW which have next format and then use PdbFileName, Signature and Age in next way

@RbMm thank you for the info! Maybe you know if there any source in internet where i can find all historic ntoskrnl binaries or their IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY?
